How can I deploy my nextjs app to whm and cpanel?
I didn't find a good way to deploy my next app to whm.
I installed nodejs and prerequisites and set the application manager. when I run curl command, it returns HTML, but it's not working on my website. I also set .htaccess but site didn't work.
I'm confused. Can someone explain to me how to deploy nextapp and where is my mistake?
Thanks .
